# Frustating - iOS Safari/Chrome jQuery modal dialog - Preventing background scrolling

Tags: jquery, ios, modal-dialog, mobile-safari, jquery-ui-dialog

i searched in many place and i tryed alot of solution and workaround for preventing body background scrolling after the modal is open.

Actually, for Android, and Desktop work very perfectly.

The Only problem is with iOS.

After the modal dialog open, i can scroll the background body and all go glitched (like see the overlay, modal-dialog disapper (up or down), cannot exit from overlay, cannot scroll anymore) sorest stuck in the webpage without can do nothing.

So for now, the only workaround i can think is when mobile is activated,
i show the modal dialog for the entire size of screen........ i thinked... yes  can workaround but iOS fu*k me again

So at the point where i'm now, i can glich iOS safari/chrome only when the content of modal is less of height i upload 2 pics just for understand what i mean

[scroll bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB2GE.jpg)

[no scroll bug, when the content of modal is more of height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks2cD.jpg)

`var previousScrollY = 0;
    jQuery('#comp-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        previousScrollY = window.scrollY;
        var button = jQuery(event.relatedTarget);
        var pid = button.data('pid');
        var modal = jQuery(this);
        modal.find('.modal-body > .body-content').html();
        jQuery.get('/compatibility_ajax.php?p=' + pid, function (data) {
            modal.find('.modal-body > .body-content').scrollTop(0);
            modal.find('.modal-body > .body-content').html(data);
        });
    });

    jQuery('#comp-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var $screensize = jQuery(window).width();
        if ($screensize < 768) {
            var modal = jQuery(this);
            modal.css('margin-top', jQuery(window).scrollTop());
            modal.css('height', window.screen.height);
            modal.find('.modal-body').css('height', 'calc(100vh - 124px)');
        }
    });

    jQuery(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        jQuery('html').removeClass('modal-open').css({
            marginTop: 0,
            overflow: 'visible',
            left: 'auto',
            right: 'auto',
            top: 'auto',
            bottom: 'auto',
            position: 'static'
        });
        window.scrollTo(0, previousScrollY);
    });
});`

Comment: Probably not much help, but who knows.... iOS 13 changed certain things with default actions of modal dialogs. (So my first question is do things work properly in iOS 12.) Apple introduced "cards" (I may be wrong with the nomenclature, but basically, users can simply swipe away a modal). Yes, none of this has to do with JQuery in any way, shape, or form - so please, don't swear at me :) - but, focusing on the iOS side of your question, is there something you can do to make these modals full screen?

Comment: at the end i understand how to trick, because the problem is when the content inside the modal is less for start the internal scrolling.  So i just add some text by default under the content just for create a internal scrolling when the content is just 1-2 record and its work fine =)